# Marker list conversion for google maps api end with the Error (type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Tags: json, flutter, google-maps, google-places-api, flutter-getx

I'm using the Google New Nearby Search API to generate a list of markers of places around me and I'm getting this error

```
type '\\\_Map\\\<String, dynamic\\\>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

I'm new at flutter but I managed to get a response back i think the error is happening when convertnig from json after calling the api
this is the json body i get

```
{
     "places": [
         {
             "id": "ChIJH1SlB1OgHBURC9Io_36xG2Y",
             "formattedAddress": "XV9F+7MW, Amman, Jordan",
             "location": {
                 "latitude": 31.968225099999998,


                 "longitude": 35.874212299999996
             },
             "displayName": {
                 "text": "Sido AlKurdi Mosque",
                 "languageCode": "en"
             },
             "photos": [
                 {
                    
                     
                 },
                 
             ]
         },
         {
             "id": "ChIJtXIJhK2hHBURntIqDaJGrNg",
             "formattedAddress": "Al Imam Muslim 22, Amman, Jordan",
             "location": {
                 "latitude": 31.9706942,
                 "longitude": 35.882999399999996
             },
             "displayName": {
                 "text": "مسجد بر الوالدين (ضاحية الحسين)",
                 "languageCode": "ar"
             }
        }
     ]
}
```

I have converted it to JSON using the dart2json plugin

this is my repo

```
abstract class HttpRepository {Future<Response?> googleNearbySearch({required Map<String, dynamic> payload,});}}
```

and this is the implementation of the repo

```
class HttpRepositoryImpl extends GetConnect implements HttpRepository {
  @override
  Future<Response?> googleNearbySearch({
    required Map<String, dynamic> payload,
  }) async {
    var response = await post(
      ApiUrls.googleNearbySearch,
      headers: googleMapsHeaders,
      payload,
    );
    if (response.isOk) {
     
      return response;
    } else if (response.unauthorized) {
      CustomToast.unAuthorized();
    } else if (response.hasError) {
   
      CustomToast.backEndError(message: "something went wrong");
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

this is my controller I'm using getx and get_connect to handle my API calls the code is not complete since I removed some snippets of it

because it is too long  if anyone wants to help me and finds the code lacking I can provide it later

```
class NearbyMosquesController extends GetxController {final HttpRepository httpRepository;final CacheUtils cacheUtils;
```

```
NearbyMosquesController({required this.httpRepository, required this.cacheUtils});
```

```
List<NewNearbyMosques> mapModelList = <NewNearbyMosques>[].obs;
```

```
var markers = RxSet<Marker>();
```

```
var isDoneLoading = false.obs;
```

```
Rx<NewNearbyMosques?> nearbyMosquesModel = Rx<NewNearbyMosques?>(null);
```

```
String apiKey = "********************";
```

```
googleNearbySearch() async {try {isDoneLoading(true);final payload = json.encode({"includedTypes": ["mosque"],"maxResultCount": 10,"locationRestriction": {"circle": {"center": {"latitude": 37.7937, "longitude": 32.3965},"radius": 10000.0}}});late Rx<Response?> googleNearbySearchResponse = Rx<Response?>(null);
```

```
  Position position = await determinePosition();
  googleNearbySearchResponse.value =
      await httpRepository.googleNearbySearch(
    
    payload: json.decode(payload),
  );
  var result = jsonDecode(googleNearbySearchResponse.value!.body);

  // Set<Marker> newMarkers = createMarkers();
  if (googleNearbySearchResponse.value == null) {
    return null;
  }
  mapModelList.addAll(RxList<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(result)
      .map((e) => NewNearbyMosques.fromJson(e))
      .toList());
  nearbyMosquesModel.value = NewNearbyMosques.fromJson(
    googleNearbySearchResponse.value!.body,
  );
} catch (e) {
  createMarkersFromList();
  debugPrint(
      'this is another error in the catch   ${e.toString()}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n');
  CustomToast.backEndError(
    message: 'error while calling google',
  );
} finally {
  isDoneLoading(false);
  createMarkersFromList();
  CustomToast.backEndError(
    message: 'in the finally',
  );
}
```

```
}
```

```
createMarkersFromList() {mapModelList.forEach((element) {var places = element.places;
```

```
  if (places != null) {
   
     for (int i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
   

    markers.add(
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(
          places[i].id.toString(),
        ),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
          BitmapDescriptor.hueAzure,
        ),
        position: LatLng(
          places[i].location!.latitude!,
          places[i].location!.longitude!,
        ),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: places[i].displayName.toString(),
          snippet: places[i].formattedAddress.toString(),
        ),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
    );
     }
  }
});
```

```
}
```

```
@overrideFuture<void> onInit() async {try {
```

```
  getCurrentLocation();
  await googleNearbySearch();
 
  await determinePosition();

  super.onInit();
} catch (e) {
  print('Initialization error: $e');
}
```

```
}}
```

```
this is the curl for the post call 
     curl -X POST -d '{ "includedTypes": ["restaurant"], "maxResultCount": 10, "locationRestriction": { "circle": { "center": { "latitude": 37.7937, "longitude": -122.3965}, "radius": 500.0 } } }' \ -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "X-Goog-Api-Key: API_KEY" \ -H "X-Goog-FieldMask: places.displayName" \ places.googleapis.com/v1/places:searchNearby

here I think im getting the response and converting it to a list of map\<string, dynamic\> to use it as a marker I'm not sure though as I said I'm still new
```

I'm getting the response with no problem but in the catch I get the error typed in the title

I'm expecting to get a list of markers from the locations (lat, lon) from the response so I can add it to the markers: named parameter in the Google map widget

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with GetConnect but the error looks like you are trying to jsonDecode something that's already jsonDecoded. In that case simply change

```
var result = jsonDecode(googleNearbySearchResponse.value!.body);
```

to

```
var result = googleNearbySearchResponse.value!.body;
```

It seems GetConnect already decoded the body for you.

Comment: yes you're right about that I've changed it to this                                                                     `var result = nearbyMosquesModel.value = NearbyMosquesModel.fromJson(
        googleNearbySearchResponse.value!.body,
      ); `                                                                                                                                            but it's not what is causing the error because I've changed a couple of things and the foreEach loop is printing null values only